# obtain derivative by spline interpolation

Tags: r, statistics, interpolation

there is a series of x and y values I have (but not the function itself). I would like to get derivative of the unknown function by spline interpolation of the x and y values (getting the derivat...).
My example 
EDITED

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y<-c(0.1,0.3,0.8,0.9,0.91,0.93,0.95,0.98,0.99,0.999)
```

is it possible in R to interpolate and to get the functional form of the derivative?
My problem is that I have only x and y values of a cdf function but would need to obtain the probability denisty function..so I want to get the derivative by spline interpolation...

The reason for the question is that I would need to obtain the pdf of that cdf so I am trying to spline interpolate the xy values of the cdf - please note that this is a simple example here and not a real cdf

Comment: It's very unclear to me exactly what type of curve fitting you want to do here, but if you want to find the derivatives of a cubic smoothing spline, you should look at the `?predict.smooth.spline` help page

Comment: @MrFlick hello....no I have the x and y values of a cdf which I can plot but I would need to obtain the pdf of that cdf (the derivat) so I am trying to spline interpolate the xy values I have..does it make that more clear or how could I improve the question?

Comment: The values you posted don't make any sense as a cdf. A cdf should be an always increasing function with y values from 0 to 1.

Comment: @MrFlick this is a simple example ...the cdf hast more than 1000 values which i did not want to copy in here

Comment: You really want the functional form of the derivative of a cubic spline? It's not going to be pretty...

Comment: @Gregor did not really say that it has to be a cubic spline...for a given number of points you can get a polynomial of grade n+1...but I am more interested in the slope at every position...

Comment: The slope at every position is easy, as MrFlick says there's an example in the help at `?predict.smooth.spline`. What you ask for in your question is the functional form, which is neither easy nor nice.

Comment: @Gregor I would need to estimate the KL divergence between two cdfs so have to estimate two different pdfs which is why i asked for the functional form...will the KL div also work with the slope at every point?

Comment: Can you clarify the request after these comments? (It should be possible to use `predict.smooth.spline` at any point, not just at the original data.) I can do either one if you are willing to accept restricted cubic spline estimation (from the rms-package), but there's no point in demonstrating getting the functional form if the `predict` method will work.

Comment: And share some useful data. Either use `dput` or set a seed and simulate. For the purpose of this question you could probably add a tiny bit of noise to two `pnorm` calls and get something useful.

Comment: @BondedDust getting the functional form would be great ...getting the functional form (which would at least describe the pdf) would be very helful and cubic splines at a local position would not be a problem...does that clarify?

Comment: @Gregor ...just think the problem is that the predict metho d will not really solve the problem as it looks liek to use KL divergence I need a functional from...

Comment: You only need a functional form for KL divergence if you plan on evaluating it by hand.

Comment: @Gregor oh okay..so if you dont want to do it manually which input is then accepted? When i checked here http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/FNN/docs/KL.divergence the input was described as functions which is why I asked for a functional form

Comment: Where do you see a functional form in that link??? That function just takes two matrices.

Comment: @Gregor I don't understand what's the big deal about the functional form of the derivative of a cubic spline. It is just a piecewise quadratic function.

Comment: @heinheo Are the two cdf's evaluated at the same points? That is, do you have two sets of y values but only one set of x values? Or two sets of y and two sets of x?

Comment: @RobertDodier I'm trying to figure out if there is a real reason for needing the functional form or if the OP just thinks there is... if OP wants a numeric estimate of KL divergince, I think the functional form of the PDF isn't going to help much. I mean, that's one way to do it, but why not just do it numerically and who cares about the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the functional form of restricted cubic splines to be particularly difficult to grasp after reading [the explanation by Frank Harrell](https://books.google.com/books?id=7D0mBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=regression%20modeling%20strategies%20restricted%20cubic%20splines&source=bl&ots=rmEzP_LUTR&sig=7SmosnT5SdCDTqYh4SLnsTFZhEw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=thNJVZmSOIaoogTmsYHACA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=regression%20modeling%20strategies%20restricted%20cubic%20splines&f=false) in his book: "Regression Modeling Strategies".

```
require(rms)

 df <- data.frame( x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   y =c(12,2,-3,5,6,9,8,10,11,10.5))
 ols( y ~ rcs(x, 3), df)
#--------------
Linear Regression Model

ols(formula = y ~ rcs(x, 3), data = df)

                Model Likelihood     Discrimination    
                   Ratio Test           Indexes        
Obs       10    LR chi2      3.61    R2       0.303    
sigma 4.4318    d.f.            2    R2 adj   0.104    
d.f.       7    Pr(> chi2) 0.1646    g        2.811    

Residuals

    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.1333 -1.1625  0.5333  0.9833  6.9000 

          Coef   S.E.   t    Pr(>|t|)
Intercept 5.0833 4.2431 1.20 0.2699  
x         0.0167 1.1046 0.02 0.9884  
x'        1.0000 1.3213 0.76 0.4738  
#----------
```

The `rms` package has an odd system for storing summary information that needs to be done for some of its special

```
 dd <- datadist(df)
 options(datadist="dd")
 mymod <- ols( y ~ rcs(x, 3), df)  
 # cannot imagine that more than 3 knots would make sense in such a small example
 Function(mymod)
# --- reformatted to allow inspection of separate terms
function(x = 5.5) {5.0833333+0.016666667* x +
                    1*pmax(x-5, 0)^3 - 
                    2*pmax(x-5.5, 0)^3 + 
                    1*pmax(x-6, 0)^3 }
<environment: 0x1304ad940>
```

The zeros in the `pmax` functions basically suppress any contribution to the total from the term when the x value is less than the knots ( 5, 5.5 and 6 in this case)

Compare three versus four knots (and if you wanted smooth curves then include a finer grained `...-`data argument to `Predict`):

```
 png()
 plot(df$x,df$y )
 mymod <- ols( y ~ rcs(x, 3), df)
 lines(df$x, predict(mymod) ,col="blue")
 mymod <- ols( y ~ rcs(x, 4), df)
 lines(df$x, predict(mymod) ,col="red")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: From what the book says, "restricted" cubic splines are what used to be called "natural" cubic splines, which are linear outside the range of data. That's not appropriate for approximating a cdf, since a cdf must be constant or asymptotically constant going out toward infinity in either direction. Also, unless additional constraints are imposed, cubic splines aren't guaranteed to be nondecreasing.

Comment: Indeed they are not and identifying that sort of relationship is an extremely important aspect of their practical value. I didn't actually notice that aspect of the question and when I plotted the offered example it certainly didn't look like a "CDF". I have used the `cobs`-package when I wanted non-decreasing constrained splines.

Comment: @BondedDust well..so I modified the example in the question to make it look like a cdf...thank you very much for putting in so much effort but would you maybe mind suggesting a solution which would be fine with the cdf

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at monotone cubic splines, which are nondecreasing by construction. A web search for "monotone cubic spline R" turns up some hits. I haven't used any of the packages mentioned.

Comment: updated my example to make it look like a cdf . I think you are very right with you comment above...I googed an found that here http://robjhyndman.com/software/monotonic-splines/ but that did no really take me any further...

Comment: Presumably you will have to inspect the fitted model to extract the coefficients and compute the derivative from that, along the general lines described in the answer given by BondedDust.

Comment: @heinheo By the way, how did you get the list of 1000 points of the cdf? If you have an expression for the cdf, just compute the KL divergence via numerical integration.